# UIPageViewController error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my project I'm using a UIPageViewController where I add some viewControllers on from the storyboard. I've made a really simple sample project here:
http://www.2shared.com/file/Rz0G1b5C/pageScroll.html (choose iPhone simulator) as you can see I get the error `The number of provided view controllers (3) doesn't match the number required (1) for the requested spine location` (in my real project its `transition` instead of `spine location`  however I've done everything the same as in my real project. I've already searched stack overflow but couldn't find any answer to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the hardest time figuring this out when I first used Page View Controllers, but this is happening because you're feeding the page view controller all your view controllers at once, so it is trying to display 3 at the same time but this type of book spine only supports 1 view controller at a time. Why would it take more than 1 at a time then? If you put the spine in the middle of the page (more common on the iPad I imagine), you can show two view controllers at the same time, so you'd need to feed an array into the Page View Controller each time. In most cases, you only want to show one, so when you run `setViewControllers`, you should only put your **initial** page into the controller as a one-object array.

What you want to do to flip pages is set your Page View Controller in your sample code as the UIPageViewControllerDataSource, and then use those functions to page in and out the controllers you want. The data source provides the `viewControllerAfterViewController` and `viewControllerBeforeViewController` functions, which you can use to determine which view controller comes next in the array. Your array is being declared locally, as are your controllers, so a way that worked for me when I was doing this was by making the array a variable in the header file that you reference throughout the Page View Controller, instead of declaring it locally in `viewDidLoad` as you did in your example. Fill it up like you currently are in `viewDidLoad`, but then only send an array containing the **first** object into `setViewControllers`.

```
NSArray *initialViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:0], nil];
[self setViewControllers:initialViewControllers
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:YES
              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  NSLog(@"call back success");}];
```

So, in those data source functions, you find out where the current view controllers are in your array of view controllers and then return the one in the next index, for `viewControllerAfterViewController`, or the one in the previous index, for `viewControllerBeforeViewController`:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewControllersArray containsObject:viewController]) {
        NSInteger index = [viewControllersArray indexOfObject:viewController];
        if (index < [viewControllersArray count] && index > 0) {
            return [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:(index - 1)];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewControllersArray containsObject:viewController]) {
        NSInteger index = [viewControllersArray indexOfObject:viewController];
        if (index < [viewControllersArray count] - 1) {
            return [viewControllersArray objectAtIndex:(index + 1)];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

By implementing these functions, you only have one view controller in the page view controller at a time, and you page them in and out as you need them. They stay stored in your `viewControllerArray`, so you can flip back to the same controller you left.

Comment: I edited the first code snippet to have the same completion parameter you had in your sample code :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, this is what I got so far http://www.2shared.com/file/NNjVcNmW/pageScroll.html as you can see there is an error and I'm not sure how I can add those viewControllers that are on my storyboard onto the pageviewcontroller? Can you maybe edit my code and upload it on www.2shared.com I would appreciate it I'm struggling hard on this one

Comment: You're actually really close to having it working already! Uncomment the UIViewController lines for myViewController, myViewController2 and myViewController 3, starting at `UIViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myviewc"];` and ending at `[viewControllersArray addObject: myViewController3];`. Then instead of saying viewControllers in the initialViewControllers segment, it should say viewControllersArray, that was my mistake. You also forgot to set the data source, so add `self.dataSource = self` to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Alright this seems to work but still it does only show the first view controller, what do I need to do to make the swipe event which will show the other VCs?

Comment: If you add `self.dataSource = self`, it should implement the swiping automatically. I just tried it on my iPhone and it was working.

Comment: Ohh, I see, thank you very much bro, had a hard time on this one!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27492/discussion-between-shinonuma-and-jacob-terry)